# unauthorized access exception was unhandled

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-mobile, navigationservice

I need to call an xaml file from a click event and I am using c# for my development. I have created the Xaml file and done with the design part in it, now I need to call this xaml file from my application. I tried the following

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/xxx.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

but it gives me the following error,

```
unauthorized access exception was unhandled. 
Invalid cross-thread access.
```

What's going wrong with this? I am calling this xaml file in between one of my functions where I need to show this screen designated with `.xaml`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you're trying to call the `Navigate` method from a background thread. Call it from the UI thread instead, like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/xxx.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
});
```

Edit from comments:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   if(MessageBox.Show("message", "title", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
   {
       NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/xxx.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
   }
});
```

Comment: yes actually all the contents tat start my application runs in background this was the thing were my application starts

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{ 
// some dialog box handelled // where when i click on ok button of this message box i need to show the screen xxx.xaml.
}
and this worker_dowork as been called to a bacground and run async till i get that message box.

now wat i need is when i click on the ok button in the message box it should navigate to that xxx.xaml

thanks.

Comment: I've updated the code, but not sure if that's what you mean. Are you still getting the exception when you use the NavigationService within a dispatcher block?

Comment: no i am getting different error saying tat,

1)An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)'

and

2)Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: so i tried adding the foolowing code insted of tat as suggested in forum thread whi i saw,

(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("xxx.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

for this i am getting null reference exception

Comment: You might be getting that error because it's your first page. Follow the method in this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx

Comment: Hi as said my prob is, i have an asyc thread running to load the data to my main page. Now the problem is i need to call another screen where i need to get some information from the user. once the content is loaded i need to navigate to another screen, but inside thread i couldn't call the xaml file which i need, so is there any way to call the file once the thread is stopped ?. here is the code which we used,
public override void PrepareView(IDictionary<string, string> page)
{
base.PrepareViewModel(page);
LoginSuccess(null);
Messages();
fillContent(page);
}

Comment: fillcontent(page);  is the last function called in my thread. i need to call another screen once this thread is completed. so how can i over come this problem in windows ? Thanks